# Find an asymptotic solution of a ODE system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following ODE system:

> $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+y^2-y\\ \frac{dy}{dt}=-2xy-x$

I want to prove that there exists a solution $(x(t),y(t))$ such that 
$\lim_{t\to +\infty}(x(t),y(t))=\lim_{t\to -\infty}(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$ and $(x(t),y(t))\neq (0,0)$ for any $t$.
I can prove that when $F(x,y)=6x^2y+3x^2+2y^3-3y^2$, we have $\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t),y(t))=0$. So if there exists a solution satisfying the condition,  it should be on the curve of $6x^2y+3x^2+2y^3-3y^2=0$. Then I have no idea about what I can do next. Should I try to find a special solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this answer finds the requested solution explicitly: (I am sure there are some clever arguments such no explicit solution is needed)

As the solution should approach $(x,y)=(0,0)$ with $F(0,0)=0$ at $t\to\pm \infty$, you are interested in finding all points with $F(x,y)=0$. The solution (of $x$ in terms of $y$) is given by (we take the branch with $x,y>0$ for convenience)
$$ x = y \sqrt{\frac{\frac32-y}{\frac32 +3 y}} \tag{1}\,.$$
A potential solution of your ODE is on this curve. A nice initial value is $x=0, y= \frac32$ at $t=0$.

To find a solution, we reexpress the second ODE as
$$ x = - \frac{y'}{1+2 y} \tag{2}\,.$$

Equating (1) and (2), we find
$$ - \frac{y'}{1+2 y} = y \sqrt{\frac{\frac32-y}{\frac32 +3 y}}\,.$$
This, equation can be solved by separation of variables. We obtain
$$ - \int_{3/2}^{y} \frac{dz}{z(1+2 z)}\sqrt{\frac{\frac32 +3 z}{\frac32-z}} = \int_{3/2}^{z} \frac{\sqrt{3} dz}{z \sqrt{3+ 4z - 4 z^2}}  = t \,.$$
Evaluating the integral yields the implicit solution
$$-\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac32 +y}{2y}  \right) = t\,.$$

With this, we find the (explicit) solution
$$ y= \frac{3}{2 \cosh(t) -1}, \qquad x= \frac32 \frac{ \sinh(t/2)}{\cosh(3 t/2)}$$
where $x$ was determined from (1).

You can check that $x,y \to 0$ for $t\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: We have only $dF/dt = 0$, not $F(x,y) = 0$. So, you can have $F(x,y) = \text{const} \ne 0$.

Comment: @NN2, the condition $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}(x(t),y(t))=(0,0)$ implies that $F(x,y)=0.$

Comment: @Gonçalo You're right.